Slow Performance of WordPress Site on Docker with Azure MySQL and GitHub Files
I'm using Docker to contain a WordPress site (on localhost) for a team demo project. Our setup includes:

MySQL database hosted on Azure.
WordPress files stored on GitHub, copied into the container's WordPress folder during the build process.

Issue: The site is extremely slow (10+ seconds to load each page), including the admin page. Redis cache reduced the load time by a couple of seconds, but it's still unacceptably slow.
Observation: When loading a page, the initial request (e.g., http://localhost/) remains in a 'pending' state for several seconds with no logs in the Docker container. Once the request resolves, the data is received, and the container logs the request.
Dockerfile:
# Use the official PHP image with Apache
FROM php:8.0-apache

# Use a bash shell for execution
SHELL ["/bin/bash", "-o", "pipefail", "-c"]

# Install dependencies
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends \
    bash-completion \
    bindfs \
    ghostscript \
    less \
    libjpeg-dev \
    libmagickwand-dev \
    libpng-dev \
    libxml2-dev \
    libzip-dev \
    mariadb-client \
    sudo \
    unzip \
    vim \
    zip \
    curl \
    && apt-get clean \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

# Configure GD with JPEG and Freetype support
RUN docker-php-ext-configure gd --with-freetype --with-jpeg \
    && docker-php-ext-install -j$(nproc) gd

# Install PHP extensions
RUN docker-php-ext-install bcmath exif mysqli opcache soap zip \
    && pecl install redis \
    && docker-php-ext-enable redis

# Copy the WordPress files
WORKDIR /var/www/html
COPY src/ /var/www/html/

# Set ownership and permissions
RUN chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www/html

# Expose ports for Apache
EXPOSE 80 443

# Start Apache in foreground
CMD ["apache2-foreground"]

docker-compose.yml:
version: '3.8'

services:
  wordpress:
    build: .
    ports:
      - "8080:80"
    volumes:
      - ./src:/var/www/html
    env_file:
      - .env
    restart: always
    networks:
      - wp-network
    depends_on:
      - redis
    dns:
      - 8.8.8.8
      - 8.8.4.4

  redis:
    image: redis:latest
    networks:
      - wp-network
    ports:
      - "6379:6379"
    dns:
      - 8.8.8.8
      - 8.8.4.4

networks:
  wp-network:
    driver: bridge

Troubleshooting Steps Taken:

Implemented Redis cache - minor improvement.
Adjusted Dockerfile and docker-compose.yml to add volumes and DNS resolver - no significant impact.

Questions:
What could be causing the initial request to remain in a 'pending' state for so long?
Are there any optimizations or configurations I should consider to reduce the load times?
Any advice or insights would be greatly appreciated.

10 second admin load time I generally see when external request (wp_http) is failing to connect to wordpress repository  api.wordpress.org or some other domain.
Try plugins that shows wp_http request usage to be sure if that is the case. I use "HTTP requests manager" plugin to view slow or failing wp_http requests. Plugin will show reason why request took 10 seconds and failed.
It can be curl related or limited external connection from your server.
Then you can eather block all external connections, block that domain only or fix connection issue.
